# SoapFault exception when debugging .Net webservice from android application

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I have a .NET Web Service deployed locally with address `http://localhost:8089/`. I am trying to run a simple android application using this service and perform Add function.I used my pc ip address instead of localhost. But it provides the follwing error.

> SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://localhost:8089/VideoWeb.asmx?op=add.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@405471c8

I am new to android and i have no idea how to solve this.I am not using android emulator I am running this app on my android cell phone. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated! Here is my Code.

**Code**

```
public class CallSoap {

   public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://92.168.1.9:8089/VideoWeb.asmx?op=add";
    public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "add";
    public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.1.9:8089/VideoWeb.asmx";

    public CallSoap()
    {}

    public String Call(int a,int b)
    {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("a");
        pi.setValue(a);
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
        pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("b");
        pi.setValue(b);
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Object response=null;
        try

        {

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            response = envelope.getResponse();



        }

        catch (Exception exception)

        {

            response=exception.toString();

        }


        return response.toString();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your `SOAP_ACTION` needs to be
`http://92.168.1.9:8089/VideoWeb.asmx/add`

Comment: its `http://192.168.1.9:8089/VideoWeb.asmx?op=add` when i click on service `add` function. still the same exception :/